# How to Secure Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, security, decompiling, reflector

Our team wants to create a secure interactive application in silverlight. But as I know silverlight output is loosely compiled zip file and its download on the client machine before use or run application. And it could easily decompiled using any dot net decompiler.

I have gone through the google for security in silverlight but have not found good enough resources.

How we can secure the Silverilght application from decompilation? Can someone explain the security practices which need to be followed to prevent this when creating an application with silverlight?

Comment: Just to clarify, why are you concerned about decompilation? Is it intellectual property protection or is there sensitive data contained within the code which you don't want exposed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are worried about people decompiling your Silverlight XAP file, you need a special kind of tool called [Obfuscator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code). There's a ton of alternatives for .NET but there's a few that work quite well with Silverlight, this a list of the ones I've tried or heard good comments from other people:

- [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm)
- [Code Fort](http://www.codefort.org/product)
- [Deep Sea Obfuscator](http://www.deepseaobfuscator.com/home.aspx)
- [ComponentOne XapOptimizer](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/XapOptimizer/?gclid=CKOA_eL2jqoCFQFvbAodVUEGwA)

Hope that helps!

Comment: You have to clarify what you mean by "secure"... secure for whom? your end user? your code? are you worried about reverse engineering? are you worried about people accessing data stored on the Silverlight application?